# Manually group specified terms in Aggregations

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I want to manually specify terms to group in aggregations i have a query like this

```
{
    "index": "xxx-xxx",
    "size": 0,
    "body": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "referralId": "1234567890ertyui"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "transactionType.keyword": "TRANSFER"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "sort": {
                "timeCreated": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "transfer_metrics": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "recipientBank.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "value": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "amount"
                            }
                        },
                        "volume": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "transactionStatus.keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

i get an aggregagtion like this, i am only posting the aggregation part

```
"aggregations": {
            "transfer_metrics": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "GTBank",
                        "doc_count": 39,
                        "volume": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BILL PURCHASED FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 29
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "PAYMENT FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 10
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "value": 13815
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "GTB",
                        "doc_count": 29,
                        "volume": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BILL PURCHASED FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 15
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "PAYMENT FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 13
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "value": 442097
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Gtb",
                        "doc_count": 11,
                        "volume": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BILL PURCHASED FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 10
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "PAYMENT FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "value": 6720
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "United Bank for Africa",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "volume": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BILL PURCHASED FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 2
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "value": 100
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Access Bank",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "volume": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BILL PURCHASED FAILED",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "value": 150
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

How do i tell ElasticSearch to group `GTBank` , `GTB` and `Gtb` together and probably return it under a key of a specified key of like `GT Bank`. And can I do it for multiple `recipientBank` in one query, e.g inclusive of the above i add... group `FB` , `Fb` and `First Bank` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) instead of term-based agg. Your filter, in turn, can contain a boolean query with multiple term queries. This is assuming the caller is aware of the keys to aggregate.

Comment: That's the thing, i must be aware of all the banks when using filter. What if a new bank has been added, i won't know.
That's why i want ElasticSearch to do the terms aggregation by itself, then i specify the similar ones i want it to group @nirmal

Comment: Are they known in indexing time?

Comment: No they're not pre known.....it's gotten from API providers for the payment gateway

Comment: Unfortunately, can't think of a solution, in that case, AFAIK.